# Upload file to Google Drive with C#

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

How can I upload a file to google drive, with given mail address, using C#?

Comment: http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c-upload/

Comment: You cant really do it with an email address your going to have to be authenticated to the users account in order to access their data.   Beyond that the code in the answers and the link above should get you started.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to @NicoRiff's reference, you may also check this [Uploading Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) documentation. Here's a sample code:

```
var fileMetadata = new File()
{
    Name = "My Report",
    MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
};
FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("files/report.csv",
                        System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
    request = driveService.Files.Create(
        fileMetadata, stream, "text/csv");
    request.Fields = "id";
    request.Upload();
}
var file = request.ResponseBody;
Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + file.Id);
```

You may also check on this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet).

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what you meant by "upload with mail ID". For accessing a user's Google Drive, you'll have to receive an Access Token from Google for that particular account. This is done using the [API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk).

The Access Token will be returned, upon receiving user's consent. This Access Token is used to send API requests. Learn more about [Authorization](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth)

For a start, you have to enable your Drive API, register your project and obtain credentials from the [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com)

You can then use the following code for receiving user's consent and obtaining an authenticated Drive Service

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                             DriveService.Scope.DriveFile};
var clientId = "xxxxxx";      // From https://console.developers.google.com
var clientSecret = "xxxxxxx";          // From https://console.developers.google.com
// here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId,
                                                                              ClientSecret = clientSecret},
                                                        scopes,
                                                        Environment.UserName,
                                                        CancellationToken.None,
                                                        new FileDataStore("MyAppsToken")).Result; 
//Once consent is received, your token will be stored locally on the AppData directory, so that next time you won't be prompted for consent. 

DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
   HttpClientInitializer = credential,
   ApplicationName = "MyAppName",
});
service.HttpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(100); 
//Long Operations like file uploads might timeout. 100 is just precautionary value, can be set to any reasonable value depending on what you use your service for.
```

Following is a working piece of code for uploading to Drive.

```
    // _service: Valid, authenticated Drive service
    // _uploadFile: Full path to the file to upload
    // _parent: ID of the parent directory to which the file should be uploaded

public static Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File uploadFile(DriveService _service, string _uploadFile, string _parent, string _descrp = "Uploaded with .NET!")
{
   if (System.IO.File.Exists(_uploadFile))
   {
       File body = new File();
       body.Title = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(_uploadFile);
       body.Description = _descrp;
       body.MimeType = GetMimeType(_uploadFile);
       body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = _parent } };

       byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(_uploadFile);
       System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);
       try
       {
           FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = _service.Files.Insert(body, stream, GetMimeType(_uploadFile));
           request.Upload();
           return request.ResponseBody;
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(e.Message,"Error Occured");
       }
   }
   else
   {
       MessageBox.Show("The file does not exist.","404");
   }
}
```

Here's the little function for determining a file's MIME Type:

```
private static string GetMimeType(string fileName)
{
    string mimeType = "application/unknown";
    string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext);
    if (regKey != null && regKey.GetValue("Content Type") != null)
        mimeType = regKey.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
    return mimeType;
}
```

[Source](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-authentication-c/).

Comment: This is more up to date https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/Genreated-samples1.0/Drive%20API

Comment: Also you may want to mention that he cant just use the email address he needs to be authenticated.     Thanks for the links btw :)

Comment: @DaImTo : you're welcome buddy :). .. I owe you one too...Those were some really nice tutorials over there.. Gracias! ;)