# Is there a way to upload file to google drive directly without human login using c#

Tags: google-drive-api

I want direct api can upload a file from mvc core application to google drive without redirect to login page to sign in

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload file to Google Drive with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42390307/upload-file-to-google-drive-with-c-sharp)

Comment: No, it doesn't. it still asks for login with google account

Comment: Do you mean you want to upload a file using an account that is already logged in? Or no account at all?

Comment: I want to upload a file using in-code login process @JasonE.